# How to unscrew this screw

Tags: kitchen

I want to take out my dish washer, but there is a screw that I don't know how to unscrew. I can't get the screwdriver straight on the screw head, only at an angle. Please see the pictures. Thanks.

[image: Damaged screw]
[image: Damaged screw]
[image: Damaged screw]
[image: Damaged screw]

Comment: Hi an0, Did you know there is https://diy.stackexchange.com/ for precisely this kind of question. There are already a couple of questions regarding under-counter dishwasher installations.

Comment: @Stan I didn't know. I reposted it there. I'll delete it here. Thanks.

Comment: Let's be patient. A moderator will have a look and help sort out the issue. No serious harm was done.

Comment: @Stan, this question is perfectly on-topic here.  Questions are only migrated if they are off-topic.

Comment: @at0 I would ask the question at the DIY and delete it here as you cannot post the same question on two StackExchange sites at the same time. You might wish to use the answers here, however.

Comment: @Chenmunka the question was cross posted and has an accepted answer at https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/196330/how-to-unscrew-this-screw also note the OP comment under https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/23769/13

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that someone drove in the screw in the first place, and that the bracket is slotted where it is fixed to the machine, you might be able to

- Wiggle the dishwasher back a little to expose the screw. It only needs to move about 1 cm.

It looks as though you have been able to remove the screw on the left. If you can't shift the machine further back, a more brutal attack could be

- Use a blunt chisel and hammer to force the screw out, by placing its tip between the bracket and the chipboard worktop and hitting it.

You can see from the screw holes that the bracket has been refixed in the past, so when you want to put it back, get a new screw and make another hole.

*Disclaimer: at your own risk. I can't be held responsible for any damage you might do.*

Answer (score 0):

**STOP**

The screw is holding a "clip." Do not unscrew it until you lift the white piece directly upward.

The slot in the white piece is there so that when you lift the white moulded "shell" it will clear the clip screwed into the wallboard.

After you lift the shell clear of the clip and fastener, you will gain access to the fastener to remove the screw, clip, and whatever thing the clip is holding out of view covered by the white moulded shell.

Good luck.

Comment: I added a full picture. I don't think the white shell can be lifted. It is the whole inner shell of the dish washer. I already unscrewed the left clip since that one was using the outward hole so the screwdriver can be used normally.

Comment: @an0 Thank you. I do not think this need a lifehack so much as experience or proper instructions from a manual or both. I've asked your question to be migrated.

Comment: Oops, a question can be migrated? But I've already posted it there. Sorry, what should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

You can also get an offset screwdriver at a local home improvement center or hardware store.

Comment: While this seems like a good idea, that screw is longer then the available space. If you had clearance to get the screw out, you would have room for a regular screw driver

Answer (score 0):

Pull out the bottom of the dishwasher, allowing it to tip backwards as the front slides forwards.

It should clear the clips & then allow removal.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother getting too technical with this one; just shove the dishwasher backwards hard. At the time that screw was fitted it was accessible by normal screwdriver. As time has worn on the dishwasher has been pulled/slumped forward by the weight of the contents and the constant yanking on the door, bending the clip to more like 45 degrees and rendering it inaccessible now. A good push will cause the dishwasher to move backwards and upwards, bending the clip to be more like flat again and revealing the screw head.

If that doesn't work out, hammer a pry bar (or a flat bladed screwdriver) against the side of the screw head, snapping the head off the screw (screws snap pretty easily) and refit using the other hole you can see - the one that is still accessible. It would also be possible to hammer a pry bar in and lever the screw out (pull it out of the wood) - it will be a short screw, and screwed into chipboard will have minimal pull-out resistance. Its function was never to resit being pulled out by a force perpendicular to the countertop, it was to resist the shear force of pulling the dishwasher door open (stop the dishwasher sliding forwards)

Ensure when you refit that the dishwasher is adequately supported by all its feet and is properly levelled. Wind the/a screw into the other hole (the one you can still see) instead of reusing this hole as if the same thing happens again it will be inaccessible again

Answer (score 0):

Lifehacks **HACK**: Use the **wrong** tool for the job.

If you have a pair of long-nose pliers, you have enough clearance to grip the side of the head of the counter sunk screw. You would alternately tighten the grip on the head, turn the screw a bit, loosen the plier jaws and reposition them, tighten the grip, etc.
[image: Wrong screwdriver for the job]

It shouldn't take very long before the screw falls out of the chipboard counter.

Good luck.

Comment: While this seems like a good idea, that screw is longer then the available space.  If you had clearance to get the screw out, you would have room for a screw driver.